# Symbol "?" in alias or Dirty url

Tags: drupal-6, path

I want to move the website to the Drupal CMS with original paths. It's look like

- website.com/search.php?q=blablabla
- website.com/index.php?q=blablabla
- website.com/category.php?q=auto&page=2

etc

How can i use these aliases in Drupal? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have great difficulty setting this up, if it's even possible.  It would be much better to let Drupal use its standard clean URLs and to setup URL rewrite rules to translate requests for legacy URLs to the new ones.

For example, Drupal's search URL looks like:

```
website.com/search/node/blahblah
```

And in .htaccess you could define:

```
RewriteRule ^search.php\?q=(.*)$ /search/node/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Which would match the format of your legacy search URL, extract the query and rewrite the URL so that query is in Drupal's clean form.  That way requests to website.com/search.php?q=blah get translated to website.com/search/node/blah before getting sent to Drupal.  The user however will see the new, Drupal-style URL.

[mod_rewrite is well documented](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/).

This is of course going to be harder to do if your legacy URLs make use of unique IDs that do not exist in Drupal.  In that case I'd take care to make sure that node IDs and taxonomy IDs etc all correspond between your legacy site and your new site.  That way you could translate something like /view.php?articleID=121 to /node/121.

This has the effect of handling any incoming links from search engines, third party sites, or users' bookmarks, but leaves you with an entirely new URL structure.  I've used this approach before when migrating to Drupal.